# Navigation bar buttons are not visible on iphone 5s(real device)

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, swift4, uibarbuttonitem

Navigation bar buttons are not visible on iphone 5s(real device), but works when tapped on that location. For other phones and simulators, icons and back buttons are visible.

Comment: Show your screen images and add your code what you have done.

Comment: If possible add screen shot

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? My Nav Bar icons are ther eon iPhone 6 and up but they are invisible on iphone 5s and lower devices...